# How to compare two columns of a dataframe in a scatter plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm using the  `HSAUR3` library and the `USstates` dataset, I'm trying to compare the Illiteracy column and `Life.Expectancy` in a scatter plot but I'm not able to do it:

This is what I have

```
library(HSAUR3)
data(USstates)
help(USstates)
Df <- as.data.frame(USstates)
Df
## scatter plots
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Df, aes(x = Illiteracy, y = Life.Expectancy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = Population, color = State)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',formula = y ~ x)
```

ignora that i tried to add a regression line, im just trying to get the scatter plot comparing both columns

Comment: Welcome to SO!. To help you, it would be useful if you describe what's the issue and whether you get an error (and which error message) or warning. But perhaps the issue is that the `USstates` data has no `State` column?

Comment: Hi, exactly, not having a state or area column makes it harder for me, and thank you!

Comment: But you could get a `State` column easily using `Df$State = rownames(Df)`.